# Detecting global "Ctrl" key press on OS X doesn't fully work when changing spaces

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm using the following code to globally detect when the <kbd>control</kbd> key is pressed and released in order to communicate with a Chrome extension via native messaging.

```
#import <AppKit/NSEvent.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(){
  __block bool ctrlDown = false;
  [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSFlagsChangedMask
                                       handler:^(NSEvent *event){

    int code = [event modifierFlags];

    if (!ctrlDown && (code & NSControlKeyMask)) {
      printf("%c%c%c%c", (char) (7 & 0xff),
                         (char) ((7>>8) & 0xFF),
                         (char) ((7>>16) & 0xFF),
                         (char) ((7>>24) & 0xFF));
      printf("{\"v\":1}");
      ctrlDown = true;
    } else if (ctrlDown && !(code & NSControlKeyMask)) {
      printf("%c%c%c%c", (char) (7 & 0xff),
                         (char) ((7>>8) & 0xFF),
                         (char) ((7>>16) & 0xFF),
                         (char) ((7>>24) & 0xFF));
      printf("{\"v\":0}");
      ctrlDown = false;
    }
    fflush(stdout);
  }];

  [[NSApplication sharedApplication] run];

  return 0;
}
```

This works great, *except* in a specific situation: when using <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to switch spaces/full screen apps, and releasing the <kbd>control</kbd> key *before* the animation completes, the handler is not invoked for the release of the <kbd>control</kbd> key. (If you hold <kbd>control</kbd> until *after* the animation completes, everything seems fine.)

Is there a way to fix this issue, or another API I can use to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Another API you can use is [Quartz Event Taps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-317057). I don't know if it would suffer from the same limitation or not.

Comment: Thanks @KenThomases, that API looks promising. Seems like I might need more experience than "enough to be dangerous" in able to effectively use it. :)